# Why can't row polymorphism be use to store objects in heterogeneous containers?

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml

[According to chapter 11 of Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html), row polymorphism cannot be used to create heterogenous containers.

> In particular, row polymorphism cannot be used to place different types of object in the same container. For example, lists of heterogeneous elements cannot be created using row polymorphism

The example given is:

```
type square = < area : float; width : int >;;
type shape = < variant : repr; area : float>
and circle = < variant : repr; area : float; radius : int >
and line = < variant : repr; area : float; length : int >
and repr =
 | Circle of circle
 | Line of line;;
# let hlist: < area: float; ..> list = [square 10; circle 30] ;;
    Characters 49-58:
    Error: This expression has type < area : float; radius : int >
           but an expression was expected of type < area : float; width : int >
           The second object type has no method radius
```

As the error message so clearly states, the types of the elements do not match. My question is why can't row polymorphism "hide" the methods of the records that do not match, ie do an intersection on all the types in the container?

If you follow that line of thought the logical conclusion then you would end up with a system with less type errors, but many inferred types `<>` with no methods.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but you have to do it explicitly like so:

```
let hlist = [(square 10 :> shape); (circle 30 :> shape)]
```

The reason it is not done automatically is probably that otherwise the type system would become undecidable (according to http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/objectexamples.html it is already on the verge of undecidability). But I don't know the details.